# Sistering to repair sill sag

Tags: joists

I just bought a house that had had a water issue around the sill plate. I am going to replace the sill soon but the water has caused a few of the joists to sink about 1/4". How long do the boards i sister onto the joists need to be?

Comment: Check your local regulations - that will be specified.

Comment: Adding a picture might help too.